# Build 3D surface from one 2D top-down image surface

Tags: matlab, geometry, computer-vision, computational-geometry

I am wondering if there is a way to build a random 3D surface from only one *(top-down)* 2D image of this surface. The fact is that the 3D surface needs the z-coordinates (the heights and the depths) and the 2D *(top-down)* image gives only the x and y coordinates.

I believe that the main problem is that we can't get the real ranges of the dimensions (x,y,z) of the surface from one 2D *(top-down)* image but we can get some kind of normalized scaling which is not the real one (it's just similar).

---

**For example:**

If we have an image with a surface (2D) and we want 3D of this surface (x,y,z) we can have easily the x and the y coordinates from the image. We can't have the real range of the amplitude (z coordinate) in each point of the surface but only the gray-tones scaling. Is there any ideas on how could we take the real sizes of the amplitudes of a surface from one 2D *(top-down)* image?

**Left** is a sample of 2D top-down image and **Right** is a surface which created by the 2D
http://www.sendspace.com/file/9wzx0u

p.s.
I can't post an image because of my reputation, so I uploaded one on sedspace.com.

Comment: From what I understand, you are trying to build a 3D image out of a 2D projection. It is not very clear how you want to generate the z coordinate, as you first say "random", but then mention gray-tones. Could you provide an example by posting a 2D image and a possible 3D output of it the way you want?

Comment: @Numbers i post a link with an example you asked

Answer (score 0):

Read in the image:

```
A = imread(filename)
```

Plot the surface plot using the magnitude of the value read in for each x and y from the file:

```
surf(A)
```

Comment: this will give me the magnitude of the gray scale image and actually we don't want this. We want the real heights of each x-y of the object that is captured in the image.

Here is a probability : one value with small height and one value with high height have the same gray tone. 
If we have a plato, somehow we have the phenomenon in the link and that's why many values have wrong heights.
( http://www.sendspace.com/file/nbr6aq )

The problem has easily solution if we have two images of the same surface from different angles. But how can we do this with only one image.